# c# implicit operator a matrix with parameters

Tags: c#, matrix, operator-keyword, implicit

I have this class:

```
public class SmartTable : DataTable
{
    public string this[int Row, int Column]  { ... }
    public string this[int Row, string Column]  { ... }
}
```

and i want to add an implicit operator on THIS[,]

then i could use:

```
string s = smartT[a,b];
```

or

```
int i = smartT[a,b];
```

I googled this but even I don't know how to search it.

I tried (based on IntelliSense) declare something like:

```
public static implicit operator int[int r, int c](...) {...}
```

or

```
public static implicit operator int (SmartTable sm, int a, int b)
```

and don't work.

Thanks

=== Edit ===

This is a DataTable, and a table have strings, integers, ...

I want to avoid put Convert.To--(...) every time i use this table...

If I try to put a Field on a int, is because it's a integer field...
A solution I'm using is create  iGet(int C, int R), sGet(...), dGet(...)

Comment: The problem is it looks like you want an implicit conversion from `string` to `int`, but that's not possible: the language doesn't provide it, and you cannot create user-defined conversions when both types are built-in.

Comment: @dlev I don't understand your comment or I couldn't explain what I want...  inside implicit code will be a Convert.toInt(), or a .ToString()...

Comment: If your `smartT[a,b]` returns a `string` for both overloads, how do you want it to be converted to an `int`? Does it simply do an `Int32.Parse` on the string value? Do you ever return strings that can't be converted to integers (like "Hello World!")?

Comment: @Rafael You can do that, sure, but my point is that it can't be *implicit*: you will need to do so explicitly (possibly with a method called `CallDataAsInt()`, possibly with an indexer that actually returns an `int`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your `SmartTable` design to return or work with a custom class instead of the primitive `string` type, then you can add your own implicit conversions to `int` or `string`.

```
public class SmartTable : DataTable
{
    //dummy/hard-coded values here for demonstration purposes
    public DataValue this[int Row, int Column]  { get { return new DataValue() {Value="3"}; } set { } }
    public DataValue this[int Row, string Column]  { get { return new DataValue() {Value="3"}; } set { } }
}

public class DataValue
{
    public string Value;

    public static implicit operator int(DataValue datavalue)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(datavalue.Value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(DataValue datavalue)
    {
        return datavalue.Value;
    }
}
```

And some usage:

```
string s = smartT[0, 0];
int i = smartT[0, 0];

Console.WriteLine(s);//"3"
Console.WriteLine(i);//3
```

Note that this kinda flies in the face of using implicit operators. For example, if your `DataValue.Value` is non-convertable to `int` (for example, if it were "Hello World!") it would throw an exception which is generally against the [best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) and unexpected for developers leveraging your API.

Comment: Thanks, and about the "best pratices", it's a DataTable, if someone tries to put a product description in an int variable, it should thrown an error...